# How to apply transglutaminase brand "Saprona TG F"

Tags: storage-method, ingredient-selection, molecular-gastronomy

I have transglutaminase/activa powder branded "Saprona TG F". The ingredients are Salt, Gelatin, phosphate and transglutaminase. The dose is 1%. I'm making chicken roulade - should I apply it as a powder, a slurry or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I discovered that applying this brand as a powder is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

To hydrate the gelatin you'd need to heat the slurry and I would certainly not recommend doing that.

Powder + passoire is your best bet.